# apache tomcat clustering and firewall rules

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, tomcat7, windows-firewall

We have just set up a apache 2 node tomcat(version 7) clustering using mod_jk and it appears to be functioning property.

I have

```
apache running on Machine1 
Tomcat1 instance on Machine2(port 8080)
Tomcat2 instance(8080) on Machine3.
```

All on windows servers 2012.

(We are using the default session replication Delta manager)

My question is how should i configure the firewall rules for all these machines.

```
For apache machine 1, port 80 is open for anyone. 
For machine 2, Port 8080 should it be open only from machine 1 
since its going to do the redirect?
```

What about the ports 8009 (AJP Port) ? 
Replication Port and Multicast service Port(45564) ?

Thanks!